# How to add an Extra button on Extjs grid header menu

Tags: extjs, grid, contextmenu

has anybody had the need to add an extra button to the grid panel header menu(sorting\columns)?
potentially I would like to add another button to the menu that resets to the default columns model. I can accomplish this using Jquery but I was wondering if there is an EXTjs way to do it.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You need to dig through the source to see it's there, but a `GridPanel` has a `view` property which is its `GridView` which in turn has a `hmenu` property which is the menu it shows when you click on one of those column headers.

So, with a `GridPanel` called `gridpanel` (once it's rendered) you can do the following:

```
gridpanel.view.hmenu.add({
  text: 'reset',
  handler: function() {
    // reset magicks
  }
});
```

Comment: it doesn't look like this works in ExtJS 4.1. there is no `menu` object on the view

Comment: looks like there is a typo in the post. In the beginning "hmenu" is mentioned (which is correct, at least in Ext 2, which is what I checked) but in the code snippet there is "menu" (which seems incorrect to me). It's also worth adding that "hmenu" is available for the gridpanel.view only after the panel has been rendered.