# How to add extra button to Ext.js grid header menu just for one column

Tags: gridview, extjs, extjs3

There is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4498217/how-to-add-an-extra-button-on-extjs-grid-header-menu), but I don't need new menu item to appear in every column. Just in the one it's relevant. I have looked into the [source code](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/source/GridView.html#Ext-grid-GridView) for the GridView and there is a function `handleHdDown : function(e, target)` that I was hoping I can override if I extend from the GridView to make a custom view for that. Didn't work out, but maybe I was doing something wrong.

Edit:

The version of Ext.js I'm trying to accomplish this with is 3.4

Answer (score 0):

One way to add menu on specific column is to add it on 'headertriggerclick'

Fiddle here: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/2e3

Comment: Thank you for taking a shot at this. I'm sorry if I wasn't clear, but I did link to the right version of docs. I'm dealing with legacy code and Ext.js there is 3.4, so the closest I can find in listeners is [headerclick](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.grid.GridPanel-event-headerclick). But that doesn't do it. It's not fired when header menu drops down. So unfortunately despite giving me some hope this doesn't answer my question.

Comment: 3.4 lack these features, one way to know when menu opens is to add listener for 'show' afterRender.. something like this.view.hmenu.addListener('show', function...) in 'afterrender' interested to know if you find the solution... thx!

Comment: For all people who are in 4.2, it does the job! Thanks newmount